# C++: is string.empty() always equivalent to string == ""?

Tags: c++, string

Can I make an assumption that given

```
std::string str;
... // do something to str
```

Is the following statement is always true?

```
(str.empty() == (str == ""))
```

Comment: str.empty() is more general. If one day you decide to use `std::wstring str` then `str.empty()` will work but `str == ""` will not even compile.

Answer (score 56):

#### Answer

Yes.  Here is the relevant implementation from `bits/basic_string.h`, the code for `basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>`:

```
  /**
   *  Returns true if the %string is empty.  Equivalent to *this == "".
   */
  bool
  empty() const
  { return this->size() == 0; }
```

#### Discussion

Even though the two forms are equivalent for `std::string`, you *may* wish to use `.empty()` because it is more general.

Indeed, [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian) comments that if you switch to using `std::wstring` instead of `std::string`, then `==""` won't even compile, because you can't compare a string of `wchar_t` with one of `char`.  This, however, is not directly relevant to your original question, and I am 99% sure you will not switch to `std::wstring`.

Comment: @xtofl: The answer to the original question, which only asked about std::string, is unambiguously "yes".

Comment: Also, empty() should potentially be more efficient than =="".

Comment: this answers seems very compiler-/vendor-specific to me for some reason

Comment: @slavy13: That's true.  But @D.Shawley shows that this is in line with the standard.

Comment: @A. Rex: Which means that his answer is the one that should be voted, and not yours. ;)

In C++, it is usually a mistake to trust your compiler/implementation to say anything about how the language should behave. All it can tell you is how *your* implementation behaves, not whether that behavior is 1) correct, and 2) required.

Comment: Don't be so sure about not switching to std::wstring.  You never know when corporate HQ will want to open a Japanese affiliate.

Answer (score 11):

It should be. The ANSI/ISO standard states in [21.3.3 `basic_string` capacity](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/html/oct97/lib-strings.html#lib.string.capacity):

> `size_type size() const;`
>
> **Returns:** a count of char-like objects currently in the string.
>
> `bool empty() const;`
>
> **Returns:** `size() == 0`

However, in clause 18 of [21.3.1 `basic_string` constructors](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/html/oct97/lib-strings.html#lib.string.cons) it states that the character-type assignment operator uses `traits::length()` to establish the length of the controlled sequence so you could end up with something strange if you are using a different specialization of `std::basic_string<>`.

I think that the 100% correct statement is that

```
(str.empty() == (str == std::string()))
```

or something like that. If you haven't done anything strange, then `std::string("")` and `std::string()` should be equivalent

They are logically similar but they are testing for different things. `str.empty()` is checking if the string is empty where the other is checking for equality against a C-style empty string. I would use whichever is more appropriate for what you are trying to do. If you want to know if a string is empty, then use `str.empty()`.

Answer (score 7):

str.empty() is never slower, but might be faster than str == "".  This depends on implementation.  So you should use str.empty() just in case.

This is a bit like using ++i instead of i++ to increase a counter (assuming you do not need the result of the increment operator itself).  Your compiler might optimise, but you lose nothing using ++i, and might win something, so you are better off using ++i.

Apart from performance issues, the answer to your question is yes; both expressions are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Yes `(str.empty() == (str == ""))` is always* true for `std::string`.  But remember that a `string` can contain `'\0'` characters.  So even though the expression `s == ""` may be false, `s.c_str()` may still return an empty C-string.  For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void test( const string & s ) {
    bool bempty = s.empty();
    bool beq = std::operator==(s, ""); // avoid global namespace operator==
    const char * res = (bempty == beq ) ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
    const char * isempty = bempty ? "    empty " : "NOT empty ";
    const char * iseq = beq ? "    == \"\"" : "NOT == \"\"";
    cout << res << " size=" << s.size();
    cout << " c_str=\"" << s.c_str() << "\" ";
    cout << isempty << iseq << endl;
}

int main() {
    string s;          test(s); // PASS size=0 c_str=""     empty     == ""
    s.push_back('\0'); test(s); // PASS size=1 c_str="" NOT empty NOT == ""
    s.push_back('x');  test(s); // PASS size=2 c_str="" NOT empty NOT == ""
    s.push_back('\0'); test(s); // PASS size=3 c_str="" NOT empty NOT == ""
    s.push_back('y');  test(s); // PASS size=4 c_str="" NOT empty NOT == ""
    return 0;
}
```

**barring an overload of `operator==` in the global namespace, as others have mentioned*

Answer (score 1):

Some implementations might test for the null character as the first character in the string resulting in a slight speed increase over calculating the size of the string.

I believe that this is not common however.

Comment: I would hope it *never* happens, because C++ strings claim to be able to store any characters, including possibly null characters.

Comment: Agree with A. Rex. size() should be O(1), i.e. stored anyway.

Comment: A. Rex, if you use the =="c style string", it stops comparing at the first \0 . so the optimization would be quite valid actualy.

Comment: Due to A. Rex's point - checking for NUL can only be done on the `const char*` argument; you'd *still* need to check the string itself was empty, so you're necessarily adding work over only testing for empty.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, yes.

But if someone decides to redefine an operator then all bets are off:

```
bool operator == (const std::string& a, const char b[])
{
    return a != b; // paging www.thedailywtf.com
}
```

Comment: Someone could just as easily change empty() ... or even all of the rest of the entire STL ...

Comment: actually, if this operator would be defined globally, it would be significantly easier than changing the entire STL.  I don't know if it would override the operator defined on the std::string object in that case, however...

Comment: Yeah, my point was that C++ allows you to shoot your whole foot off by redefining operators badly, so answering questions like the above will inevitably rely on caveats.

Comment: I'm actually giving this a +1 (partly for mentioning thedailywtf.com!).  I've even seen somebody defining an operator< for a priority type in terms of operator>

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is equivalent but allows the core code to change the implementation of what empty() actually means depending on OS/Hardware/anything and not affect your code at all.  There is similiar practice in Java and .NET