# Which is faster, string.empty() or string.size() == 0?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, string

Recently, during a discussion I was asked by a fellow programmer to do some code changes. I had something like:

```
if( mystring.size() == 0)
    // do something
else
    // do something else
```

The discussion was regarding the use of `mystring.empty()` to validate if the string is empty. Now, I agree that it can be argued that `string.empty()` is more verbose and readable code, but are there any performance benefits to it?

I did some digging and found these 2 answers pertaining to my question:

- [Implementation from basic_string.h](https://stackoverflow.com/a/483361/355722)
- [SO Answer that points to ISO Standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/483517/355722) - [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/wp/html/oct97/lib-strings.html#lib.string.capacity)

Both the answers buttress my claim that the `string.empty()` is just more readable and doesn't offer any performance benefits, compared to `string.size() == 0`.

I still want to be sure, if there are any implementations of `string` that keep an *internal boolean flag* to validate if a string is empty or not?

Or there are other ways that some implementations use, that would nullify my claim??

Comment: @chris: I agree with you mate. Just wanted to confirm though.

Comment: "my claim that the string.empty() is just more readable and doesn't offer any performance benefits" -- **just?** Readability is the first priority of competent programming; performance, especially at this level, trails far behind. " if there are any implementations of string" -- even if there were, if would just be a comparison of a value to zero, same as for size == 0.

Comment: @JimBalter: I also consider code readability of paramount importance, I just wanted to get input from people here on SO is the underlying implementations of empty() were faster than size()??

Comment: @all: I don't see a reason for a down-vote. I've very well expressed the question and it's a valid question.

Comment: Downvotes cannot be removed unless the question is edited.

Comment: @JimBalter, Really? That's interesting. Is there a short take-back timeout in there?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The standard defines `empty()` like this:

> > bool empty() const noexcept;
> >     Returns: size() == 0.

You'd be hard-pressed to find something that doesn't do that, and any performance difference would be negligible due to both being constant time operations. I would expect both to compile to the exact same assembly on any reasonable implementation.

That said, `empty()` is clear and explicit. You should prefer it over `size() == 0` (or `!size()`) for readability.

Comment: Agreeing with empty() being more clear. However there is a difference between size() and empty() in some cases. Tested with msvc 2015: For an std::string empty() it does size()==0 and string::size() returns a cached size (so no division). But for an vector<int>::empty() does a first()==last() and vector<int>::size() does a subtraction with an implicit division(!) - in this specific case with a bitshift. So in the case of a vector, empty() only does a comparison and avoids having to do that division. Realistically, in most cases, it won't make any noticeable difference :)

Comment: @kalmiya, Interesting, I notice Clang generates [almost identical](https://godbolt.org/g/821yyw) assembly.

Answer (score 7):

Now, this is a pretty trivial matter, but I'll try to cover it exhaustively so whatever arguments are put by colleagues aren't likely to take you by surprise....

As usual, if profiling proved you really *really* had to care, measure: there *could* be a difference (see below).  But in a general code review situation for not-proved-problematically-slow code, the outstanding issues are:

- in some other containers (e.g. C++03 lists but not C++11), `size()` was less efficient than `empty()`, leading to some coding tips to prefer `empty()` over `size()` in general so that if someone needed to switch the container later (or generalise the processing into a template where the container type may vary) no change needs to be made to retain efficiency.
- does either reflect a more natural way to conceive of the test? - not just what you happened to think of first, or `size()` because you're not as used to using `empty()`, but when you're 100% focused on the surrounding code logic, does `size()` or `empty()` fit in better?  For example, perhaps because it's one of several tests of `size()` and you like having consistency, or because you're implementing a famous algorithm or formula that's traditionally expressed in terms of size: being consistent might reduce the mental noise/effort in verifying the implementation against the formula.

*Most of the time the factors above are insignificant, and raising the issue in a code review is really a waste of time.*

**Possible performance difference**

While the Standard requires functional equivalence, some implementations *might* implement them differently, though I've struggled and so far failed to document a particularly plausible reason for doing so.

C++11 has more constraints than C++03 over behaviours of other functions that impact implementation choices: `data()` must be NUL terminated (used to be just `c_str()`), `[size()]` is now a valid index and must return a reference to a NUL character.  For various subtle reasons, these restrictions make it even more likely that `empty()` will be no faster than `size()`.

Anyway - measure if you have to care.

Comment: If your `empty` were to check for a `NUL` at the beginning of a string , it would not be correct, since `std::string` allows `NUL` characters, unlike C strings.

Comment: In C++11, the string content must be NUL-terminated. But @rici is right; an implementation that checked the first char for NUL would be broken.

Comment: I think there are quite a few good points in here apart from the nul issue. I can easily see the `size()` option working better in that context and the point about the complexity requirements varying by container is also a good one.

Comment: +1 for **measure if you care**. It works the opposite too: if one dont want to measure, then he doesnt care and question is void (assuming that measurement is possible at all, of course:D).

Comment: @rici: ironic... got following links to another question on empty string detection and just finished addressing the exact same issues about NUL on some else's answer only to find I'd overlooked it myself.  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD: I don't think nullptr will work either, since even the empty string needs to be NUL-terminated and the NUL needs to have a dereferenceable address, if accessed through the `data()` member function. I'm not sure that adding a test for nullptr on every data() call (and probably every begin()/end() call as well, although it might be the case that data() and begin() could return different pointers) would be described as "vaguely sane".

Comment: @rici: Say the empty-string condition stores `end_ = 0` and `begin_ = (char*)&end_`: then I believe the obvious simplest implementations of `data()`, `operator[]` and `c_str()` all work (assuming nullptr is all 0 characters on your architecture), trading faster `empty()` for slower `end() { return end_ ? end_ : begin_; }` (with knock on effects to `size()`). Compared to the compromises made for short-string optimisations this isn't huge, and if the string also uses SSO it can be expected to make quite a lot of these branching choices anyway... any closer to sane? :-)

Comment: @TonyD: Trading slower `end()` and `size()` for a (possibly) faster `empty()` strikes me as a wildly unlikely choice for a general purpose library, with or without SSO. I mean, if you're going to store the size in end_ when the size is 0, you might just as well always store the size in end_ (possibly coming up with a more meaningful member name), since `end() { return begin_ + size_; }` is not going to be slower than your conditional on any reasonable hardware. I can see the arguments for the two-pointer approach, but I think that the `begin_/size_` model is common in actual implementations.

Comment: @rici: ok - I'm convince no sane implementation will do that either, and thinking about it more the obvious SSO implementation might let you check if `end_` pointed at the first character of the internal buffer, which will be a fixed offset from `this`, but it's only one indirection less than comparing to `begin_`.  Re what actual implementations do - I looked at Visual C++ and GCC maybe 12 months ago, and my recollection is they both store `begin` and `end` - idiomatic iteration seems prioritorised over `size()`, which seems fair to me.