# Checking for empty string in C++ alternatives

Tags: c++

There are (at least :) two ways of checking if an string is empty in C++, in particular:

```
if (s.length() == 0) {
  // string is empty
}
```

and

```
if (s == "") {
  // string is empty
}
```

Which one is the best from a performance point of view? Maybe the library implementation is clever enough so there isn't any different between them (in which case other criteria should decide, i.e. readibility) but I tend to think that the first alternative (using `length()`) is better.

Any feedback on this, please? (Or even a 3rd method better than the ones I have proposed).

Comment: How about `std::string::empty`?

Comment: What about S == null?

Comment: @marshalcraft There's no `null` in C++ (it's called `nullptr`), and also a `std::string` variable cannot be null. Only pointers can be null.

Comment: @marshalcraft Even in languages where that would be valid, such as Java, "no string at all" is not the same as the empty string.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can also use `empty`

```
if(s.empty())
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! As far as I read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539626/which-is-fast-string-empty-or-string-size-0, empty() is a kind of alias for a checking based on size() (which, in secuence, seems to be equivalent to length()). That would confirm my guessing about the first one is the best one (at least good enough so library designers are providing the "official" method to check emptyness based on that :)

Comment: @fgalan - Library implementors are also free to make the check as a simple `internal_buff == nullptr || *internal_buff == NUL_CHAR`. The library designers only require `size == 0` to hold as well :)

Comment: We profiled this mess a few weeks ago based on the exact same debate and found .size() == 0 to be the fastest, but nobody proposed s.empty() to even check, and the inlineable extant library function has *got* to be the fastest way.

Comment: .empty() should be fastest in almost all implementations. This is because for non-empty strings, using .size() will unfortunately continue counting the number of characters beyond 1, simply to tell you it's not empty. The .empty is more efficient because most implementations only check whether the first character is either null terminated, or returns false immediately when count reaches 1. Also, the reason .size() = 0 is faster than checking == "" is because "" requires a call on an implicit string constructor, although many compilers will optimize this out.

Comment: What if my string is just '\0'?

Answer (score 16):

You can use the following:

```
s.empty();
s.size() == 0;
!s.size();
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use `empty` from string [library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/empty/)

```
string.empty()
```