# Check to see if a string array value is null/empty C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Ok so i want to check to see if the value of the array, `array1` is empty and if it is, it should not be put in `array2`. How do i do this?

```
    for (int i =0; i < 70549; i ++)
        {
            std::size_t found = array1[i].find(result[1]);

            if (found!=std::string::npos)

                array2[i] = array1[i];              
        }   
    cout
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to accomplish? If you explain the underlying purpose of the task you'll get a better answer.

Comment: `if (array1.size() > 0)`, perhaps?

Comment: (but why do you call a string `array1`?...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483337/c-is-string-empty-always-equivalent-to-string

i hope this might help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want `std::copy_if`. I'm not sure what condition you want. In English you describe the C++ function `.empty()`, but your C++ code implements a test "string contains the substring `result[1]`". `std::copy_if` can work with both.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want the string's `empty()` method. You could expand your condition like this:

```
if (!array1[i].empty() && found != std::string::npos)
    array2[i] = array1[i];
```

Obviously that will leave unchanged (presumably blank) values in `array2` though, where the `array1` values weren't copied across. If that's not what you want then you'll need to keep a second loop counter which will index `array2`. It will only be incremented every time you actually copy a value across.

Comment: Yes, I don't want empty values to go in `array2` but what do you mean a second loop?

Comment: A second loop **counter** (i.e. another index variable within the same loop). Currently you're always accessing index `i` in both arrays. If you want to avoid leaving blanks in `array2`, you'll need to index it using a separate counter (e.g. called `j`): `array2[j] = array1[i];`